# Closure of temples

Tags: dharma, dharma-shastras

Generally temples are closed during the afternoon. Can anybody enumerate the reasons why they are done so ? Quotes from our Dharmashastras, if any would be welcome.

Comment: agama shastras dictate all these rules about temples.